# I get an error in python3 when importing mechanize

Tags: python, python-3.x, mechanize

I get an error in python3 when importing mechanize.

I've just installed mechanize into my virtualenv where python3 is installed.

```
$ which python3
/Users/myname/.virtualenvs/python3/bin/python3

$ pip freeze
mechanize==0.2.5
```

But, when I try to import mechanize in my python code, I get this error.

```
import mechanize

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-6b82e40e2c8e> in <module>()
----> 1 import mechanize

/Users/myname/.virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/mechanize/__init__.py in <module>()
    117 import sys
    118 
--> 119 from _version import __version__
    120 
    121 # high-level stateful browser-style interface

ImportError: No module named '_version'
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

I'm new to python and I've been studying how to program in python these days.

Thanks for your help in advance!

**update**

I've installed [mechanize for python3](https://github.com/adevore/mechanize/tree/python3).
Now, I have an another error.

```
In [1]: import mechanize
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-6b82e40e2c8e> in <module>()
----> 1 import mechanize

/Users/myname/.virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/mechanize-0.2.6.dev_20140305-py3.3.egg/mechanize/__init__.py in <module>()
    120 
    121 # high-level stateful browser-style interface
--> 122 from ._mechanize import \
    123      Browser, History, \
    124      BrowserStateError, LinkNotFoundError, FormNotFoundError

/Users/myname/.virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/mechanize-0.2.6.dev_20140305-py3.3.egg/mechanize/_mechanize.py in <module>()

/Users/myname/.virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/mechanize-0.2.6.dev_20140305-py3.3.egg/mechanize/_html.py in <module>()

ImportError: cannot import name _sgmllib_copy
```

I checked what I've installed in my working virtualenv.
I found some warnings.

```
$ pip freeze
cssselect==0.9.1
httplib2==0.8
ipython==1.1.0
lxml==3.2.4
## FIXME: could not find svn URL in dependency_links for this package:
mechanize==0.2.6.dev-20140305
pyquery==1.2.8
Warning: cannot find svn location for mechanize==0.2.6.dev-20140305
```

Comment: That's odd, I tried installing right now and it worked...

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you're installing the Python 3 version of the library? Python 3 changed the semantics for relative imports, this breaks a lot of Python 2 code. Also, did you try importing the module from the interactive interpreter?

Comment: @rectangletangle
I tried to import mechanize in ipython in terminal.

Comment: @rectangletangle oh, you mean if I installed mechanize that's for python3? I didn't check if the one I installed through pip command is for python3.

Comment: I have the same problem installing python3 branch of mechanize

Answer (score 15):

Alas, mechanize doesn't support Python 3. http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/faq.html

> Python 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, or 2.7. Python 3 is not yet supported.

You might like to comment on the issue at https://github.com/jjlee/mechanize/issues/96

---

Update: I wrote my own automating library MechanicalSoup. It's Python 3 compatible    https://github.com/hickford/MechanicalSoup

Comment: Thanks for the MechanicalSoup lib! It has been a huge help. :)

Answer (score 5):

The module MechanicalSoup merged Mechanical and BeautifulSoup in the same Library and can be used since Python 2.6 through 3.4.

in command prompt install MechanicalSoup:

```
pip install MechanicalSoup
```

Then import in python,

```
import mechanicalsoup # Don’t forget to import the new module
```

Comment: Typo? I guess you meant Mechanize (not _Mechanical_) and BeautifulSoup. But that's not correct: [MechanicalSoup](https://github.com/MechanicalSoup/MechanicalSoup) is built on Python [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) (for HTTP sessions) and [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) (for document navigation) ... so it does not use Mechanize. I think they just named it like that to remark it does a similar work as Mechanize, plus the benefits provided by BeautifulSoup. But thanks a lot for letting me know about this new great tool !

Answer (score 2):

I think you may have installed the Python 2 version of mechanize, and the new Python 3 import semantics are breaking the old Python 2 code. A quick search, and it seems like Python 3 support for mechanize is still a bit weak. However, I did find a [Python 3 branch](https://github.com/adevore/mechanize/tree/python3).

You could try manually installing from the source code I linked to. Once you've downloaded the source, change your directory so that you're in the mechanize directory. Then enter `$python3 setup.py install` in the terminal.

Comment: Thank you for you help! I've just installed the one you link to. But, I got another error. I'm going to edit my post to add the information.