# Installing mechanize for python 3.4 on windows 8.1

Tags: python

How to install mechanize in python 3.4 on windows 8.1

I tried `pip install mechanize`

It had a few syntax errors in installation but finally it said `Completed Successfully`

Still `import mechanize` doesn't work

It says `No module named 'mechanize'`

Comment: How doesn't it work? `No module named mechanize`?

Comment: What was the output of `pip install mechanize`? Did it succeed?

Comment: there were some syntax error messages while it was being installed but finally it said `successfully installed`

Comment: Can you verify if `pip list` outputs mechanize, and can you show us what happens when you try to import mechanize

Comment: `pip list` shows `mechanize(0.2.5)` in the list

Answer (score 2):

From [mechanize FAQ](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/faq.html) :

*Which version of Python do I need?
Python 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, or 2.7. Python 3 is not yet supported.*

But you could have a look to this other recent post from SO [I get an error in python3 when importing mechanize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190503/i-get-an-error-in-python3-when-importing-mechanize) if you want to test the version in developpement for python3.

By the way, did you try googling "mechanize python3" before asking on SO ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have both python 2.X.Y and 3.z on your machine you will also have both pip and pip3 you may have installed machanize for python 2 rather than python 3.

Try:

```
pip3 install mechanize
```

Answer (score 0):

try running

```
py -m install mechanicalsoup
```

it worked on my Windows 10 with Python 3.6
Good Luck