# Installing python package

Tags: python, pip, mechanize

I've already installed mechanize using `pip install mechanize`, such that when I enter it in the command prompt, the response is: `Requirement already satisfied: mechanize in c:\users\wwl\anaconda3\lib\site-packages`.

However, when I type `import mechanize` in the jupyter notebook, it gives an error:

`ImportError: No module named '_mechanize'`.

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: What version of python are you on? Mechanize only supports python 2.*

Comment: I didn't know that. I'm on Python 3. Thanks for mentioning.

Comment: No worries :) [Here's some alternatives](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/3dvq25/are_there_any_better_alternatives_to_mechanize/)

Comment: have you tried installing using `python -m pip install mechanize`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Virtualenv?

If so, make sure you are importing the global libraries to your virtualenv (https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/#removing-an-environment).

If not, probably your Python version is not compatible. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24001585/2051397

Hope it helps