# howto solve import error in mechanize module

Tags: python, web-scraping, mechanize, mechanize-python

I'm trying to learn mechanize module but getting this *import error* while doing the basic thing

I got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "C:/Users/HUNTER/PycharmProjects/Encryption/erp.py", line 2, in <module>
    import mechanize  
  File "C:\Users\HUNTER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\mechanize\__init__.py", line 119, in <module>
    from _version import __version__  
ImportError: No module named '_version'
```

by doing this

```
import mechanize 
br = mechanize.Browser() 
br.open("website")
```

Comment: Please post the whole traceback.

Comment: @roganjosh i did

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190503/i-get-an-error-in-python3-when-importing-mechanize) help?

Comment: @roganjosh i tried to install it manually but getting the same error , but what about the __version_, im still on basics and it would be really helpful if you could relate the answer to my previous question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42719990/how-to-request-a-website-to-log-in)

Comment: The link in that first answer still points to a page saying that Python 3 isn't supported. I don't use the module but it seems a likely explanation, even though it's nearly 3 years old. What version of Python are you using?

Comment: @roganjosh its 3.5.2

Comment: @roganjosh are there any alternatives for `mechanize`

Comment: That I really don't know. As I said, I don't use the library.